# Using Google maps on iOS application (App Review)

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native-ios, react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl

I am using Apple Developer program.

In my mobile (React Native iOS *(and Android)*) app I am using Google maps.

Can I go on App store like that, or I need to use iOS maps if I want to submit my app to App Store? Will I pass App Review with Google maps?

Comment: Of course you can use Google Maps. Google Maps on AppStore is using Google Maps too :)

Comment: @ÖmerBaş and is that free for use? https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/ this confuses me

Comment: It's free to use on the mobile side. On the web side it became pricey.

Comment: StreetView, Routes, Places, Geocoding, Elevation services are all payed. Static and dynamic mobile maps aren't.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that I worked on an application that is in production, pubblished on the App Store that is using Google Maps